# Hyperref and titlesec conflict and warning

Tags: packages, warnings

When I use the `titlesec` and `hyperref` packages in the same document, I get a warning when I try to add subsection titles to the ToC with this code:

```
\subsection*{This is subsection}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{This is a subsection}
```

The warning states:

> Package hyperref Warning: The anchor of a bookmark and its parent's must not be the same. Added a new anchor on input line 12.

This warning only appears when **subsections** are added to the ToC in this way, not **sections**. Line 12 is where the subsection is added. Here is a minimal working code showing the isse ([live demo here](https://www.sharelatex.com/project/58e4e28a54b8ca05149425b0)); the section part is not triggering the warning, only the subsection parts:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\section*{This is a section}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{This is a section}

\subsection*{This is subsection 1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{This is a subsection 1}

\subsection*{This is subsection 2}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{This is a subsection 2}

\end{document}
```

I have found out that removing any of the `titlesec` or `hyperref` packages removes the warning. How can this conflict between the packages be fixed and the warning removed?

Comment: `titlesec` changes many things internally considering the section commands and as such, the hyper anchor commands are wrong. You need a `\phantomsection` before each manual addition

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use a `\phantomsection` before each manual addition of a `\subsection*` to the `ToC` (and bookmarks) in order to reestablish the hyper anchors.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\section*{This is a section}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{This is a section}

\clearpage
\phantomsection
\subsection*{This is subsection 1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{This is a subsection 1}

\clearpage
\phantomsection
\subsection*{This is subsection 2}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{This is a subsection 2}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

With a similar problem and a complex preamble, and also having a couple of `\addcontentsline`s, I've found a simple solution in making sure that `hyperref` is loaded after `titlesec`, as actually recommended in `hyperref`'s manual.

Answer (score 1):

You can also include, in the preamble:

```
\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\phantomsection}
```

This does not seem to mess up numbered sections, and applies consistency throughout the document.  You can also throw a `\clearpage` in the definition to get your "sections start on a new page" automatically.