# Subsubsubsection (paragraph) not showing in TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, paragraphs

To add a sub-sub-sub-section (aka a `paragraph`), I followed the instructions here:

- [How to add an extra level of sections with headings below \subsubsection](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60209/how-to-add-an-extra-level-of-sections-with-headings-below-subsubsection)

Now, this works great, however, I noticed that the `paragraph` will not show in the TOC. How can I add it to the TOC?

To complicate things further, even though I do not want the `paragraph` to be numbered, and so, I write `\paragprah*{}`, I still want it to show in the table of content. To do that, I tried to follow:

- [Adding unnumbered sections to TOC](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11668/adding-unnumbered-sections-to-toc)

**Is there a way I can have a** `paragraph` **that is unnumbered + still shows in the TOC?**

Here is the code I have, which is a combination of the two links above:

```
\documentclass[a4,12pt]{article}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\paragraph}
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}
{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\newpage
\section{Section}
\subsection{Sub section}
\subsubsection{Sub sub section}
\paragraph{Sub sub sub section}

\end{document}
```

Comment: How about `\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}` and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/210688/170958)?

Comment: Or of course `\renewcommand{\theparagraph}{}`

Comment: Or `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}` plus `\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}`, that's probably the best fix (since `\renewcommand{\theparagraph}{}` might well mess with the spacing in the ToC)

Comment: I tried these solutions, and they do not seem to work. I think am getting close because I can see that in the TOC, there is an extra "white space" indicating that the paragraph is there, and I can click on a very small hyperlink box to go to the paragraph, but its not written in the TOC. Do you mind modifying the code above to one that works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Approach 1:

```
\documentclass{article}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Section}
\subsection{Sub section}
\subsubsection{Sub sub section}

%\phantomsection % recommended if you're gonna use titlesec + hyperref, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/364010/hyperref-and-titlesec-conflict-and-warning
\paragraph{Paragraph 1}
\paragraph*{Paragraph 2}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot1]

Approach 2:

```
\documentclass{article}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Section}
\subsection{Sub section}
\subsubsection{Sub sub section}

%\phantomsection % recommended if you're gonna use titlesec + hyperref, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/364010/hyperref-and-titlesec-conflict-and-warning
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/210688/170958
\paragraph*{Paragraph 1}
%\label{par:paragraph}
\addcontentsline{toc}{paragraph}{Paragraph 1}

\paragraph{Paragraph 2}

\paragraph*{Paragraph 3}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot2]

Comment: Bless your soul! This works perfectly in my much larger document. Thank you very much.